# kubernetes etcdctl where is it?

Tags: kubernetes, etcdctl

Silly question.  Just setup a 4 node kubernetes cluster (one master node).  The etcd pod is running in the kube-system.  But I can not find the etcdctl in regular path.

```
# find / -name etcdctl -print
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9c0f2f2ef864f3be6f4195cbcda59b712805fc1957204b97d36a9239e3adb1cf/diff/usr/local/bin/etcdctl
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf2ff1f903bef67c6ed8ddf0b37cc6a90788974f61275df5d5fe3d9bdaca232c/merged/usr/local/bin/etcdctl
```

Used the found etcdctl to take snapshot but it's hung.  Do I need to install etcdctl?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to `docker`, what you have found is the volume mount for the etcd container, and inside that container is the `etcdctl` binary that is designed for use with the `etcd` binary inside the container.

You will want to `docker exec` into the container so you will have access to all the environment variables, config files, hostnames, etc that would be required to interact with `etcd`. [Their documentation](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.3.18/Documentation/op-guide/container.md#running-a-3-node-etcd-cluster-1) shows an example of using `docker exec`.

The [fine manual](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.3.18/Documentation/op-guide/recovery.md#snapshotting-the-keyspace) also describes that you will want to ensure the `ETCDCTL_API` environment variable is correctly set while using `etcdctl`.

Comment: So to backup the kubernetes etcd, I'll need to exec -it to the etcd container to run the etcdctl command?  
I tried to use the master node public IP address as the endpoint IP but get connection closed error when running etcdctl inside the container.

Comment: You can backup etcd with etctl using ETCDTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 \ you can find more information on [Kubernetes Community](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/etcd-backup-and-restore-management/11019)